# VMWare Fusion accessible hostname on network

Tags: networking, ip, lan, vmware-fusion

I have a virtual machine with Windows 8 running. This VM is configured as a shared network with my Macbook Pro. From my Macbook Pro, where i'm running the VM I can access the ip address over the network. 
But when I try to access it on a different computer in the network I can't access it. When I change my network configuration to bridged I can access it, but when i'm on another location, the ip address of the VM is changed. And thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem was that i needed to add ".local" after the hostname. For example my VM has a hostname "CoolMachine", the url in the browser wil be "CoolMachine.local" :)